# How can I resuse the same Asynctask class for returning different data types?

Tags: android, casting, android-asynctask, return

Is there a generic type of signature when extending the Asynctask class ; smthg like ; `Asynctask<String,Void,<generictypehere>>` so as to enable to cast the return the result value from the thread and be able to cast the returned value to any daa I wish? For instance I want to be able to use the same asynctask class which creates HttpUrlConnections to different urls ,passed as parameters to the class, and sometimes I want to download html code which is String type and sometimes Bitmap, depending on the url.

Is it possible? if so how?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. Use a [generic class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html).

E.g.

```
class MyAsyncTask<ReturnType> extends AsyncTask<String,Void,ReturnType> {
```

Comment: I agree with this solution, but I think you should add a code example alongside your link.

Comment: thnx..I will try...but then how shall I call the class constructor? Like:  " MyAsynTask<Bitmap> newInstance=new MyAsyncTask<Bitmap>(); ...right????

Comment: example: `new MyAsyncTask<String>()`